# Crystal Reports Formula Variable not reset to 0 in Group

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a report...
Its a kind of Ledger Report..
I am displaying the report Groupwise by Name.
See the below image displaying the error...

[image]
Now see the red marking in the image...
I created the formula shown below..

**d_ClosBal**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar ClosBal1;
ClosBal1 := 0;
ClosBal1 := Sum({@DebitAmt}) - Sum({@CreditAmt});

IF ClosBal1 > 0 then ClosBal1 else 0;
```

**c_ClosBal**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar ClosBal1;
ClosBal1 := 0;
ClosBal1 := Sum({@DebitAmt}) - Sum({@CreditAmt});

IF ClosBal1 < 0 then ClosBal1 else 0;
```

And Placed formula in the yellow mark shown in the figure below...

[image]

The Sum({@DebitAmt}) is 5740.00 and Sum({@CreditAmt}) = 800.00 shown in figure

The blue marked are the Transactions, ex 1000.00, 945.00, etc....
I even tried putting a formula reseting the value of ClosBal1 to 0 inside GroupHeader but ain't helped.

Suggest me any solutions..

Answer (score 0):

you need to indicate your group levels in this statement otherwise you are just grouping the entire report.

ClosBal1 := Sum({@DebitAmt}) - Sum({@CreditAmt});

example

```
ClosBal1 := Sum({@DebitAmt},{companyname}) - Sum({@CreditAmt},{companyname});
```